# Create rational function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I have to create a rational function with the characteristics:
3 real zeros(1 of them of multiplicity 2).
y-intercept 1.
vertical asymptote at $x=-2$ and $x=3$.
oblique asymptote $y=2x+1$.
I've tried with various functions but the y-intercept and the oblique asymptote characteristics seem to be impossible to satisfy at the same time.
I had something like:
$$\frac{2(x-a)^2(x-b)}{(x+2)(x-3)}$$
and i tried solving for a and b trying to satisfy the y intercept but the solution isn't rational. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: Rational functions must be expressible as the ratio of two polynomials, it is not required that the coefficients be rational numbers. e.g. $$ \frac{x-\pi}{  x-\sqrt 2} $$ is a rational function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost did all the work (may be you forgot to add the conditions  $(a\neq -2, a\neq 3 , b\neq -2, b\neq 3) $.

Now, using the formula you proposed, perform  the long division to get
$$y=\frac{2(x-a)^2(x-b)}{(x+2)(x-3)}=2 x-(4 a+2 b-2)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ which makes
$$4 a+2 b-2=-1 \implies b=\frac{1}{2}-2 a$$

So $$y=\frac{2(x-a)^2 \left(x+2a-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(x-3) (x+2)}$$ If $x=0$ then
$$\frac{1}{6} \left(a^2-4 a^3\right)=1$$ The cubic equation in $a$ shows only one real root which is $\approx -1.06715 $.

If you want to look fancy, using the hyperbolic solution to get
$$a=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{6} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(1295)\right)$$

Comment: i tried that but when you use that de y intercept must be 1. you get that a or b are roots of prime numbers so they are not rational

Comment: also i think you solved wrong the $4a+2b-2=-1$ it should be $b=\frac{1}{2}-2a$

Comment: @NuKexZ. Sorry, I missed the $y$ intercept.

Comment: Ah, ok my problem with this function is precisely the y intercept.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the definition of a rational function.  A rational function is simply the quotient of two polynomials.  In most contexts there's no need for the coefficients of those polynomials to be rational.

Comment: @JohnOmielan. Thanks for pointing my stupid mistakes !